# Display Rss Feed in Android

Tags: android

My requirement is to get the data from the RSS feed and display it on a list view.and when i click on the list item the details of that item should be displayed in a new activity. the data i am getting from RSS feed is around 50kb to 80 kb so which parser is better to use either SAX or DOM.

Comment: then????? where is your code? have you tried any thing?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take SAX. If I remember correctly SAX uses less memory (and is even faster). SAX reads the data sequential while DOM takes it all into memory and then parse it there.